# automating regex to process multiple files

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to process some data - specifically I have to

1. Delete any decimals from all numbers in the file, eg `4.0 -> 4`
2. Add a dash between any dates and any times, eg `2014-01-01 23:45:52 -> 2014-01-01-23:45:52`

I've wrote some regexes in sublime text to do this using the find and replace function:

1. Find : `"\.\d"`, Replace : `""`
2. Find : `"(\d{2})\s(\d)"`, Replace : `"$1-$2"`

This all works fine and gives me the right results. The problem is that I have to process hundreds of csv files in this way, I've tried to do it in python but it isn't working the way I'd expect. Here's the code used:

```
for file in csv_list: # csv_list is the list of all the files I need to process
with open(file, "r") as infile:
    with open("{}EDIT.csv".format(file.split(".")[0]), "w", newline="") as outfile: # Save the processed version
        writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=",")
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        for line in reader:
            writer.writerow([re.sub("(\d{2})\s(\d)",
                            "$1-$2", re.sub("\.\d", "", string)) for string in line])
```

I'm not too confident with regex, so I can't see why this isn't working the way I'd expect. If anyone could help me out that'd be great. Thanks in advance!

As requested, here is an input row, what output I was expecting, and what the actual output is:

```
input : 0.0,2013-01-01 20:59:39,5737.0,english,2013-01-01 21:01:07,active
desired output : 0,2013-01-01-20:59:39,5737,english,2013-01-01-21:01:07,active
actual output : 0, 2013-01-$1-$20:59:39,5737,english,2013-01-$1-$21:01:07
```

Comment: Replace `"$1-$2"` with `r"\1-\2"`

Comment: Specify what it is currently doing, and what you expect it to do (give us examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve your issue by replacing the first regex pattern with `r"\1-\2"`:

```
import re
rx = r"(\d{2})\s(\d)"
s = "0.0,2013-01-01 20:59:39,5737.0,english,2013-01-01 21:01:07,active"
result = re.sub("(\d{2})\s(\d)", r"\1-\2", re.sub(r"\.\d", "", s))
print (result)
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/3GTzGt). See the [`re.sub` reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

> Backreferences, such as `\6`, are replaced with the substring matched by group 6 in the pattern.

Or, to avoid that fuss with string replacement backreferences, use a single regex for that task and modify the matches inside a lambda expression:

```
import re
pat = r"\.\d|(\d{2})\s(\d)"
s = "0.0,2013-01-01 20:59:39,5737.0,english,2013-01-01 21:01:07,active"
result = re.sub(pat, lambda m: r"{}-{}".format(m.group(1),m.group(2)) if m.group(1) else "", s)
print (result)
```

See [another Python demo](http://ideone.com/eHbpKr).

Note that perhaps, for better safety, you could use `r'\.\d+\b'` as the pattern to remove decimal parts (`\d+` matches one or more digits, and `\b` requires a char other than letter, digit or  `_` after it, or the end of string). The second pattern can be spelled out for the same purpose as `r'(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\s(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'`.